# Timeout error when i download files using FTP Task?

Tags: ssis

I have ssis package in that i used FTP Task.

When i Using FTP Task i download .csv file, i got operation timeout error.

The file size is 20 MB.

Please help me how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you set the timeout period to 0 it will not timeout. You should be aware that the remote host could still close your connection, so you will want to catch that situation.

The setting is in the FTP Connection Manager:

[image: FTP Connection Manager]

Answer (score 2):

If you are just downloading files, look at your "Use passive mode" setting in the "FTP Connection Manager Editor" and make sure it is selected.